# Create only one application and use it over different spec files

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I was trying to test my different spec files, but I do not want to create an application for each of them, I tried to do something like this:

```js
describe('Run the project tests', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleRef: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule.forRoot({
          providers: [...environment.storage.providers()],
        }),
      ],
    })
      .compile();
    const globalApp = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
    await globalApp.init();
  });

  myTests();
```

Where `myTests()` is another spec file, and pass the `globalApp` instance down to `myTests()`, but it did not work. Is there another way to do it, maybe using a global setup file?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Nest testing. But it looks like you can module that async function and call it on every beforeAll?